# I am running GBT in Spark ML for CTR prediction. I am getting exception because of MaxBin Parameter

Tags: java, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql, decision-tree, apache-spark-ml

Exception details :

> - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: DecisionTree requires maxBins (= 32) to be at
>     least as large as the number of values in each categorical feature,
>     but categorical feature 4139 has 16094 values. Considering remove this
>     and other categorical features with a large number of values, or add
>     more training examples.   at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
>     at
>     org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.impl.DecisionTreeMetadata$.buildMetadata(DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:133)
>     at
>     org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest.run(RandomForest.scala:137)
>     at
>     org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree.run(DecisionTree.scala:60)
>     at
>     org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.GradientBoostedTrees$.org$apache$spark$mllib$tree$GradientBoostedTrees$$boost(GradientBoostedTrees.scala:208)

```
GBTClassifier gbt = new GBTClassifier().setLabelCol("indexedclick").setFeaturesCol("features_index").setMaxIter(20).**setMaxBins(16094)**.setMaxDepth(30).setMinInfoGain(0.0001).setStepSize(0.00001).setSeed(200).setLossType("logistic").setSubsamplingRate(0.2);
```

I want to know what should be the correct max bin size because If even I am setting large value of MaxBin also causing the same exception.

Your small help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the max bins to 1 more than the number of entries in the largest categorical feature, in this case set it to 16095.
i.e setMaxBins(16095)